# ActivityNotFoundException in library projecy while the Activity is there and is declared in Manifest

Tags: android, eclipse, exception, library-project, activitynotfoundexception

I am trying to [use this library](https://github.com/edsilfer/custom-searchable). But the library project as well as the demo project on the github page is for Android Studio, but for some reason I use Eclipse. So I added the library and the demo project to Eclipse (see below for how I did that) and uploaded them here:

- [customsearchable - library Eclipse project](http://www.mediafire.com/download/38gqq6jw0rmtwrm/customsearchable.rar)
- [demo - demo Eclipse project](http://www.mediafire.com/download/1kd6of0ygode7yb/demo.rar)

So what I did was that I **created a new library project in Eclipse and copied** all the files from the github library project. Following screenshot shows my project structure:

I added this library project to my demo project **just like we add the app_compat v7 project.**

[image]

Then I went on the create a **demo project** in Eclipse and copied all the files and resources from the demo project in their github repository.

**But when I run it, it gives me `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {br.com.edsilfer/br.com.customsearchable.SearchActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`**

Following are the Logcat of the demo project, and the manifest of the library project:

***FROM LOGCAT OF DEMO PROJECT:***

```
08-22 02:53:26.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2405): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-22 02:53:26.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2405): Process: br.com.edsilfer, PID: 2405
08-22 02:53:26.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2405): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {br.com.edsilfer/br.com.customsearchable.SearchActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
08-22 02:53:26.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1777)
08-22 02:53:26.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1501)
08-22 02:53:26.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3745)
08-22 02:53:26.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3706)
08-22 02:53:26.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:820)
08-22 02:53:26.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4016)
08-22 02:53:26.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3984)
08-22 02:53:26.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at br.com.edsilfer.Main.onOptionsItemSelected(Main.java:82)
08-22 02:53:26.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2885)
08-22 02:53:26.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:353)
08-22 02:53:26.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:144)
08-22 02:53:26.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:99)
08-22 02:53:26.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:541)
08-22 02:53:26.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:811)
08-22 02:53:26.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:153)
08-22 02:53:26.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:958)
08-22 02:53:26.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:948)
08-22 02:53:26.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:598)
08-22 02:53:26.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:139)
08-22 02:53:26.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
08-22 02:53:26.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
08-22 02:53:26.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
08-22 02:53:26.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-22 02:53:26.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
08-22 02:53:26.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
08-22 02:53:26.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-22 02:53:26.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-22 02:53:26.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
08-22 02:53:26.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

***MANIFEST OF LIB PROJECT:***

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="br.com.customsearchable">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="22"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="br.com.customsearchable.SearchActivity"
                  android:launchMode="singleTop"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible"
                  android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

---

***EDIT # 1***

After being pointed [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157616/using-an-android-library-project-activity-within-another-project) by @MFaisalHyder I added the following element to the `<application>` element of the demo project:

```
<activity android:name="br.com.customsearchable.SearchActivity"
                  android:launchMode="singleTop"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible"
                  android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent" >
        </activity>
```

Now, after touching the `Search` action from the toolbar, I get:

```
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104): Process: br.com.edsilfer, PID: 2104
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.edsilfer/br.com.customsearchable.SearchActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757)
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:916)
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at br.com.customsearchable.SearchActivity.onCreate(SearchActivity.java:66)
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     ... 10 more
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/br.com.edsilfer-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:571)
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     ... 22 more
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):         ... 25 more
08-22 04:44:31.332: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

---

***EDIT # 2***

The above error was resolved by adding the `<activity>` element for the `SearchActivity` in my project's Manifest. Now I am getting `android.view.InflateException: Error Inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout`. I have added the design library. Below you can see the logcat for the exception and the project properties for the design library project

**Logcat**

```
08-22 05:44:34.827: E/AndroidRuntime(2582): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-22 05:44:34.827: E/AndroidRuntime(2582): Process: br.com.edsilfer, PID: 2582
08-22 05:44:34.827: E/AndroidRuntime(2582): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.edsilfer/br.com.customsearchable.SearchActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
08-22 05:44:34.827: E/AndroidRuntime(2582):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
08-22 05:44:34.827: E/AndroidRuntime(2582):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
08-22 05:44:34.827: E/AndroidRuntime(2582):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
08-22 05:44:34.827: E/AndroidRuntime(2582):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
08-22 05:44:34.827: E/AndroidRuntime(2582):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-22 05:44:34.827: E/AndroidRuntime(2582):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
08-22 05:44:34.827: E/AndroidRuntime(2582):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
08-22 05:44:34.827: E/AndroidRuntime(2582):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-22 05:44:34.827: E/AndroidRuntime(2582):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-22 05:44:34.827: E/AndroidRuntime(2582):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
08-22 05:44:34.827: E/AndroidRuntime(2582):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
08-22 05:44:34.827: E/AndroidRuntime(2582): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
08-22 05:44:34.827: E/AndroidRuntime(2582):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
08-22 05:44:34.827: E/AndroidRuntime(2582):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
08-22 05:44:34.827: E/AndroidRuntime(2582):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
08-22 05:44:34.827: E/AndroidRuntime(2582):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:916)
08-22 05:44:34.827: E/AndroidRuntime(2582):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
08-22 05:44:34.827: E/AndroidRuntime(2582):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
08-22 05:44:34.827: E/AndroidRuntime(2582):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
08-22 05:44:34.827: E/AndroidRuntime(2582):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
08-22 05:44:34.827: E/AndroidRuntime(2582):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
08-22 05:44:34.827: E/AndroidRuntime(2582):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
08-22 05:44:34.827: E/AndroidRuntime(2582):     at br.com.customsearchable.SearchActivity.onCreate(SearchActivity.java:66)
...
08-22 05:44:34.827: E/AndroidRuntime(2582): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
...
08-22 05:44:34.827: E/AndroidRuntime(2582): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/design/R$styleable;
...
...
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.design.R$styleable
...
08-22 05:44:34.827: E/AndroidRuntime(2582):     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

[image]

---

***EDIT 4:***

After deleting (from the emulator) and reinstalling the app, **it works somehow**, i.e. there is no exception in the appearance of the activity, **but the voice search and search suggestions still don't work. =/**

Comment: <activity android:name="br.com.edsilfer.br.com.customsearchable.SearchActivity"
                  android:launchMode="singleTop"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible"
                  android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent" >
        </activity>
try activity name with the parent package name as well then let me know

Comment: @MFaisalHyder "try activity name with the parent package name as well" - Assuming that you are talking about the Manifest of the library project which is posted in the question, The name of the Activity is `SearchActivity`. I already appended the parent package name to it, thus making it `android:name="br.com.customsearchable.SearchActivity"`.

Comment: @MFaisalHyder or are you asking me to add that to the manifest of the dmeo project? The package `br.com.edsilfer` is in the demo project, while the package `br.com.customsearchable` is in the library project. I am not sure of what you asked. Can you clarify, then I'll do it and report back.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157616/using-an-android-library-project-activity-within-another-project
check this thread

Comment: @MFaisalHyder From that answer, "Declarations should reference the library components by their fully-qualified package names" - so I believe the fully qualified name of the Activity is `br.com.customsearchable.SearchActivity`. Am I right?

Comment: I am posting my answer, i will try to detail it as much as possible, meanwhile try check this all activities in Library Projects are declared in manifest or at least the one which your calling in your APP?

Comment: @MFaisalHyder Cool. Please also see the edit in my question. Thank you so very much indeed for your time.

Comment: you need to add design support library for this error.

Comment: @sourabhbans Is this library in the SDK?

Comment: yes you can find it like : 

D:\00_DEVELOPEMENT\00_DEVELOPEMENT\sdk_android\extras\android\support

Comment: and import it into eclipse and make sure to check the copy into work space..

Comment: @sourabhbans Right after I imported the design support library into my workspace, I got  a ton of errors in console. You can find them [in a text file here](http://www.mediafire.com/view/9jv4j7nl9y6cnn1/1.txt), adding to the question was increasing my question text limit

Comment: how you are using Intent? post intent part as well

Comment: go to the properties of your design library>>select android>>check android version 5.0 or above>> check is library>>add library app compat_v7>> click apply and ok

Comment: @sourabhbans Did all that. See the screenshot in the last edit in the question

Comment: @sourabhbans See my last edit at the bottom of the question. If you can post all things you said as an answer, I'll be glad to accept it. It will help any future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, the launcher intent filter is missing...

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="br.com.customsearchable.SearchActivity"
                  android:launchMode="singleTop"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible"
                  android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent" >
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Try with this, and let me know if it works.

Comment: But this is a library project, what is the use of a launcher there!

Answer (score 1):

check these two links for help :
[One](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157616/using-an-android-library-project-activity-within-another-project).

Before using any activity of Library Project its every activity and other parts must be declared in the Manifest file.

For your Intent part try like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("base.package.name.of.your.app","br.com.customsearchable.SearchActivity");
startActivity(i);

//*****Another way******\\
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),br.com.customsearchable.SearchActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

One more thing: some people also found that it is the problem of Eclipse ([Like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946258/android-unable-to-find-explicit-activity-class-startactivity-from-a-preferen)) so do try to update Eclipse.

Hope i helped you.!

Comment: Hi, this problem was resolved after adding the Activity declaration to my project's manifest. But then I got `exception`, because I had not added the  support design library. I added it, but still getting this exception. Adding an edit in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the error you are facing,because of missing design support library.
you can follow the steps to import.
go to the properties of your design library>>select android>>check android version 5.0 or above>> check is library>>add library appcompat_v7>> click apply and ok