# Didn't find class "com.imagerecognition.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList

Tags: java, android

here is the project I got from my tutor, I got the error after running it on my test phone. I tried the answers on stackovetflow but nothing helps. The logcat and manifest.xml are as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.imagerecognition"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8" 
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".TakeBusinessCardActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">

            <!--<intent-filter>-->
                <!--<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />-->

                <!--<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />-->
            <!--</intent-filter>-->
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".HistoryActivity" android:label="拍摄历史"/>
        <activity android:name=".DecodeActivity" android:label="解码"/>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

[image: logcat]

Comment: Try cleaning your project and rebuild.

Comment: seems like you have two activity declared `ACTION_MAIN` intent filter.

Comment: @FireSun, I can't find it. details?

Comment: @ParagKadam, I tried,including reboot eclipse and even computer. But it didn't help

Comment: Ok now try this -> Invalidate caches/ restart

Comment: Your `TakeBusinessCardActivity ` and `MainActivity` both declared `IntentFilter` with `ACTION_MAIN`,maybe this problem,you can remove one and try.

Answer (score 0):

This following method worked for me. Right click on your `project` and select `properties`. The "Properties for " panel will open. From the menu on the left go to `Java Build Path` -> `Order and Export` . From the list below uncheck the box next to `Android Dependencies`. Finally `clean` your project and `run`.

**Reference** : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523167/android-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-on-path)

Comment: Ok now try this , file -> Invalidate caches/ restart

Answer (score 0):

try to change your

`android:name=".MainActivity"`

to fully specified name

`android:name="com.imagerecognition.MainActivity"`

sometime eclipse act weird.

if it does not work you can try this 
[unable to find activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946258/android-unable-to-find-explicit-activity-class-startactivity-from-a-preferen/9552169#9552169)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the imports and importing them manually again.